# how do I paste the return error from api into the input field in vue

Tags: json, vue.js

I was given an api return as below:

```
 errors: {
    campaign_name: ["The campaign name field is required."],
    probability.0.prize_name: ["The probability.0.prize_name field is required."],
    probability.0.promotion_id: ["The probability.0.promotion_id field is required."],
    probability.1.prize_name: ["The probability.1.prize_name field is required."],
    probability.1.promotion_id: ["The probability.1.promotion_id field is required."],
    }
```

and I want to paste all the return errors into the input section to display on the front end

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Prize Name</label>
   <input type="text" v-model="data.prize_name" :name="data.prize_name"
   :class="['form-control', ifErorr ? 'is-invalid' : '']" :disabled="IsLoading">
   <small class="text-danger"> error message here </small>
</div>
```

I am using vue, how can I parse all those return errors?

Comment: Either use `<pre>your errors here</pre>` or get all the keys of your `errors` object in there. How is the error displayed exactly and what is your http call looking like?

Comment: @kissu how do i call a property like this `probability.0.prize_name` ?

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of the result? Very unlikely that this is the final result indeed.

Comment: Is that "api return" supposed to be JSON or a JavaScript object? In either case that is not valid. In JSON (and in JS property names that aren't valid identifies, in this case because of the dots) the property names need to be quoted. Try reading up on some basic JS syntax such as: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics Other than that your question is lacking a lot of context. Try breaking down the problem into much smaller pieces.